# Only show contacts with phone numbers?

Tags: android, contacts

This code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
```

Shows all contacts in phone.

It's possible show contacts with only phone number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It shows only contacts with phone number, you should set the type of contacts (with phone numbers only):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```